# JConsole connection failed to Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, jconsole

I am following the steps provided by the documentation.

https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/collecting-kafka-performance-metrics/#collect-kafka-performance-metrics-with-jconsole

I added these fields:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9123 
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=MY_EC2_IP_ADDRESS
```

And I tried in local JConsole
With

MY_EC2_IP_ADDRESS:9010

and I tried with 9999 and 9123 ports also.

and with username and password. But I am getting:

```
Connection Failed, Operation time out.
```

Comment: Added variables where? You should export KAFKA_JMX_OPTS variable, not add/edit any files. Also, last I checked, JConsole is for your own debugging, nothing related to Datadog, which uses its own jmxfetch or JVM agent collector

Comment: You should skip to Part 3 of the blog if you actually want to "use Datadog"